# Variant of N-Queens algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, chess, backtracking, n-queens

I don't know whether this problem has been studied or not, it just came to my mind while trying out the general N-Queens problem. Given a `N*N` chessboard , what is the minimum number of Queens required, which, when placed strategically, renders all cells under attack by at least one of the queens.

I tried it with pen and paper for `N` = 3,4,5, I got 2,3,4. So is the answer always `N-1`? Is there a proof for it? And secondly, if so, how to print out that configuration (if more than 1 configuration is possible, print them all)?

Comment: Huh? On a 3*3 board, there's only 1 queen needed (placed in the middle). Did you mean N-2 queens, perhaps?

Comment: Oh right, indeed 1 is required. So how to find out for a given number of queens?

Comment: Yeah, for 4 it looks like 2, not 3. So will the answer always be `N-2`?

Comment: From the comment discussion I assume a queen can guard itself. If not - 3x3 board does need 2 queens.

Comment: No, the answer will not always be `n-2`. A queen can cover up to `4(n-1)` squares if placed in the middle, so an lower limit for queens is `n^2/(4n-1)` which is `n/4` for large n. If the queens are placed on the rim, the lower limit is `n/3`. Why don't you write a program to find out the minimum for distinct values? :-)

Comment: @hirschhornsalz: Your lower bound of n/4 is just that -- a lower bound.  There's no reason to assume it is tight.

Comment: @j_random_hacker No of course not. Replace "not alaways" by "most likely not". A "I found out by pen and paper it is 2,3,4 (and did it even wrong)" is surely no better estimate.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz: The OP presented a guess as a guess. You presented a mathematical argument as proof when it was not.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes. Unfortunately I can't edit my comment any longer, so I leave it there to always remember me of my my hybris. Hopefully the public humiliation will teach me something ;-)

Comment: @hirschhornsalz: Fair enough :-P

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been studied and the minimum number at which `k` queens cover an `n`x`n` grid is known as the *domination number*.

The `k` for the first `n` are

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9
```

as given by [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A075458). This means for an 8x8 board 5 queens are sufficient.

It has been conjectured that for all n which satisfy `n=4m+1` (such as 5,9,13...) `2m+1` queens are sufficient. This and lot more advanced algorithms are presented in [Matthew D. Kearse and Peter B. Gibbons, "Computational Methods and New Results for Chessboard Problems"](https://researchspace.auckland.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/2292/3642/133chess.pdf)

Comment: How to do code it so that it returns the result for any given `n`? Any algorithm?

Comment: @Cupidvogel A naive approach: Start with k=1. Iterate `k` queens over a `nxn` board. Test in each iteration if all squares are covered. If you found at least one position where all squares are covered, you are done. Otherwise increase k and repeat.

Comment: Yeah, of course I can do that. But if I give that answer in an interview, they will kick me out immediately! What about an optimal solution?

Comment: There is no "optimal" algorithm for solving this problem. Study the paper which I linked, there are some "good" algorithms mentioned. But I suspect if you give one of them as an answer in an interview, they will kick you out even faster. The algorithm I gave will always give you correct minimum, why do you think its not a good answer?

Comment: How can someone kick me if I give an optimum solution as an answer? The one you mentioned is essentially brute force, right?

Comment: @Cupidvogel I would kick you because you propose a solution with a difficult, hard to implement algorithm which you need weeks to get it running, when a easy solution is available which can be done in a day. No I wouldn't, just kidding :-) All known algorithms are brute force. So what? Do really think an interviewer expect you to solve a problem where no non brute force algorithm is known with a non exponential solution? The question more interesting to the interviewer is: Are you able to find a working algorithm at all and implement it? Are you?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not N-2, because an 11x11 grid requires at most 8 queens (and possibly fewer -- this is just an example I found by hand):

[image: 11x11 grid covered by 8 queens]